# String matching for anagrams

Tags: string, algorithm, match, hashcode, checksum

I have some data, which is like `(x,y,TEXT)` and it is a representation of strings that will be put out on the screen at a given `(x,y)` position. The `TEXT` contains also control characters for color and font data, and other control characters (ignored for now). I parse out all the control characters for color, font, size and other and remain only with alphanumeric stuff at the end.

This data is generated by an application for a scene (using a nice GUI but that's not my concern now), so there are more than one entries like this that compose a final scene. Such as: `(6, 1, "Berlin")` and `(10,2 , "Hauptbahnhof")` will give a final scene, looking more or less like (imagine the graphics below as an information screen):

```
 0123456789....
0+----------------+
1|     Berlin     |
2|  Hauptbahnhof  |
3+----------------+
```

Now, the application generates the objects for the final scene in a totally unpredictable (and uncontrollable, closed source app) order, so  a final scene is either the first or the second.

- `(6, 1, "Berlin")`  `(10, 2, "Hauptbahnhof")`. I end up with -> `BerlinHauptbahnhof`
- `(10, 2, "Hauptbahnhof")`  `(6, 1, "Berlin")`. I end up with -> `HauptbahnhofBerlin`

There can be dozens of `(x,y,TEXT)` entries representing a scene, some of them even having only one character (such as: each letter is printed with a different color, or the characters are placed alongside the diagonal of the screen, or in a wave form).

And for the hardware device interpreting this data it's not important either because all the text will go to the screen at the correct place.

But ... I am supposed to match the full text from the scene with the `final` order of: `Berlin Hauptbahnhof` which comes as p(l)aintext to me. So now I need to come up with an algorithm returning a checksum/hash, not depending by the order or characters which gives me the same result as the `final` for the messed up ordered characters of the string.

As an example:

`"This is a fox"` should give the same `"a fox This is"` (just the words are messed up) and `"T h i s i s a f o x"` (all the characters are from different blocks, possible different colours) but not the same as `"This is a pex"` (`'e'` is one less that `'f'` and `'p'` is one more than `'o'` so a simple addition checksum would fail for this case). Merging/Sorting them also is not an option since in that case "eat big fish" would be equal to "bag thief is" (ie: anagrams would give the same result).

So what other options do I have?

Comment: Why does `(2, 10, "Hauptbahnhof")` put the string on the second row, and not the 10th?

Comment: @Kevin because I made a typing mistake ... :) Fixed the question.

Comment: Your examples aren't so clear.  `T h i s i s a f o x` looks like 10 separte "words" because there are spaces between, yet it's supposed to give the same hash as `This is a fox`.  Yet you say "eat big fish" should yield a _different_ hash from "bag thief is".  This is contradictory.  How do we tell where the word breaks are?

Comment: I agree with @Gene. Can't discuss a solution without a valid problem statement.

Comment: As I read it, the problem can be restated more simply and understandably as looking to check if two sequences of words can be rearranged (just the words, not the letters of the words) in such a way as to reach the same string with spaces removed (the fact that it gets rendered on a GUI, and that coordinates are involved, appears to be without consequence, although I'm not sure what to make of you mentioning diagonals and wave form). One would expect words to be able to overlap in a GUI, but this doesn't appear to be allowed. Please clarify if my understanding is / assumptions are correct.

Answer (score 0):

An abstract way of thinking about this is that you are really hashing a histogram of the words.

In this case a histogram is just a set of pairs `<word, count>`.  If you adopt the convention that these pairs are sorted by word, then the histogram representation is canonical and you can use any standard hash function you like to get an order independent hash code.

For example in Java, you might build a `HashMap` mapping words to counts and then take the `hashcode` of this map.

So the remaining problem is how to detect words in the input.  Your examples seem to contradict each other, but I'll assume that one or more spaces connote a word break.

@Kevin's method of emulating screen generation is one approach. At the end of each screen painting, you can accumulate the words.

Another is as follows:  Maintain an array of [interval trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree), one per screen row, where each interval also stores the text it represents.  Process a new datum (x,y,text) by inserting it into the interval tree.

When intervals are found to be adjacent to each other during insertion, concatenate them, including the strings they contain.  (This is very much like coalescing free blocks in a memory allocator during the `free` operation.)

At any time, each interval tree will list the words on each row.  Therefore, at any time, you can use them to find a hashable histogram as above.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the `(x, y, text)` data, then you can create a `Screen` class that emulates the hardware screen. Then you can check that two Screens are equal by comparing their string representations against one another.

Sample Python implementation:

```python
class Screen:
    """emulates the hardware screen"""
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        """initialize state with some sensible values"""
        self.data = {}
        self.width = 0
        self.height = 0
        if data != None:
            for x, y, word in data:
                self.put_message(x, y, word)
    def put_message(self, x, y, message):
        """puts a message on the screen, adjusting the height/width to fit if necessary"""
        self.height = max(self.height, y+1)
        self.width = max(self.width, x + len(message))
        for idx, c in enumerate(message):
            self.data[(x+idx, y)] = c
    def __repr__(self):
        """returns a string which represents the contents of the screen"""
        ret = ""
        for y in range(1, self.height):
            row = "\n"
            for x in range(self.width):
                #fetch the character at this position, or a period if none exists
                row = row + self.data.get((x,y), ".")
            ret = ret + row
        return ret

def compare(first, second):
    print first
    print second
    if str(first) == str(second):
        print "\nThese are equal."
    else:
        print "\nThese are not equal."

data_a = [(6, 1, "Berlin"), (2, 2, "Hauptbahnhof")]
a = Screen(data_a)

data_b = [(2, 2, "Hauptbahnhof"), (6, 1, "Berlin")]
b = Screen(data_b)

data_c = [(0, 1, "This is"), (1, 2, "a fox")]
c = Screen(data_c)

compare(a, b)
compare(a, c)
```

Result:

```
......Berlin..
..Hauptbahnhof

......Berlin..
..Hauptbahnhof

These are equal.

......Berlin..
..Hauptbahnhof

This is
.a fox.

These are not equal.
```

Here, we see that `a` and `b` have the same output, even though their inputs have different orders. And `c` obviously doesn't compare equal to either of them.

Comment: I don't think he's trying to match screens.  He's trying to compute a checksum on screen contents that can operate on the stream of incoming text data _without_ emulating screen construction.

Comment: I guess I should have explicitly said in the post, that I don't think you can match a scene's full text unless you completely emulate the screen. Any sorting/histogram/etc techniques will give false positives for non-matching strings like "eat big fish" and "bag thief is".